# How to loop an item from Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

This is my store in Vue dev tools:

[image: this is my state]

[image: this is my getters]

This is my Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <div
        v-for="product in allProducts"
        :key="product._id"
      >
        {{ product.brand }}
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  data() {
    return{
      allProducts:[],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["allProducts"])
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("getProducts");
  }
};
</script>
```

If I use this:

`{{allProducts}}`

I get all the products.

But when trying to loop with this:

```
 <div
        v-for="product in allProducts"
        :key="product._id"
      >
        {{ product.brand }}
      </div>
```

it doesn't display.

Please, how can I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

`allProducts` is object with property `products`, so in order to loop products try `product in allProducts.products`

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      allProducts: {
        products: [
          {brand: 'aaa'}, {brand: 'bbb'}
        ]
      }
    };
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="product in allProducts.products">
    {{ product.brand }}
  </div>
</div>
```